# How do you iterate through a List and go back to the first element if it reaches the end?

Tags: java, list, loops

So I have a List of objects.  I want to iterate through them with a ListIterator but I want the .next() to return the first element if it reaches the end and keep iterating through the list again.  Is that possible?

```
ListIterator<Post> postsIterator = posts.listIterator(); //posts only has 3 elements
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
{
  System.out.println(postsIterator.next().getText());
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ListIterator<Post> it = posts.listIterator();

for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    it = it.hasNext() ? it : it.listIterator();
    System.out.println(it.next().getText());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use some stream magic to create an iterator that actually goes on for ever:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");

Iterator<String> it = Stream.generate(() -> strings).flatMap(List::stream).iterator();
for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
    System.out.println(it.next());
}
```

If you have Guava available, there is a method [`Iterators.cycle(Iterable)`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterators.html#cycle-java.lang.Iterable-) that does what you want.

Maybe a slightly easier way would be to avoid using an iterator altogether:

```
List<String> strings = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three");

for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
    System.out.println(strings.get(i % strings.size()));
}
```

Comment: `() -> strings` requires some explanation please.

Comment: So `() -> strings` is a supplier lambda expression.  The result of executing it is the `strings` list.  The `flatMap(List::stream)` then turns the list into a stream, and then it is returned as an iterator.  See the Javadoc for `Stream.generate(...)` here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate(java.util.function.Supplier)

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset the `ListIterator` to the index, `0` once it reaches at the end.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = List.of("A", "B", "C");
        ListIterator<String> itr = list.listIterator();

        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
            if (!itr.hasNext()) {
                itr = list.listIterator();
            }
            System.out.print(itr.next() + "\t");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
 A  B   C   A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B   C   A   B   C
```

Comment: There're only `12` elements (not `15`)!

Comment: @oleg.cherednik - Thanks for pointing it out. Corrected it now.

Answer (score 2):

Why not to simply track your iteration variable? like this:

```java
ListIterator<Post> postsIterator = posts.listIterator(); //posts only has 3 elements
for (int i = 0; i < posts.size(); i++) {
    if (!postsIterator.hasNext()) break;
    Post post = postsIterator.next();
    System.out.println(post==null ? "" : post.getText());
    if (i==posts.size()-1) {
        i=-1; //to make sure that increment gets to 0
    }
}
```

If you insist you want to have a hardcoded threshold `15`, then:

```java
ListIterator<Post> postsIterator = posts.listIterator(); //posts only has 3 elements
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    if (!postsIterator.hasNext()) postsIterator = posts.listIterator();
    Post post = postsIterator.next();
    System.out.println(post==null ? "" : post.getText());
}
```

Comment: wouldn't you need to do 'i-=2' because it's being counteracted by i++?

Comment: When `i` gets to the `size()-1` we first fetch the element and then reset the `i`. I'm not sure I completely understood what you mean.